# Eclipse Che IDE does not start

Tags: eclipse, installation, debian, eclipse-che

today I wanted to test new Eclipse Che project. I downloaded it for Debian, then I run command:

```
bash bin/che.sh run --skip:uid --remote:192.168.0.108 --port:8080
```

The output from this command is:

```
    docker@debian:/home/eclipseche$ bash bin/che.sh run --skip:uid --remote:192.168.0.108 --port:8080
Docker is natively installed and reachable...

############## HOW TO CONNECT YOUR CHE CLIENT ###############
After Che server has booted, you can connect your clients by:
1. Open browser to http://localhost:8080, or:
2. Open native chromium app.
#############################################################
```

But then I enter the ip to my browser but it doesnt seems to work ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED does it mean that the server hasnt started ? Because I dont even see any pprocess in top. SO how should I correctly start the server ?

Comment: Do you mean "the ip" 192.168.0.108, or localhost?

Comment: This is local IP inside my network I have one linux PC where I am installing it and second windows pc from where I am trying to connect.

Comment: well, i'm currently have the same problem and i'm trying to figure it out.   "docker ps" says no process.

Comment: Found it, atleast for my case. I removed some lines from the che.bat. The block under the comment: "#Che requires Java 1.8 or higher". Now tomcat/catalina is starting.

Comment: Sorry i meant che.sh of course. And it seems normal that docker ps prints nothing because it's running direct tomcat.

Comment: Does Che startup normally (if you try to go to `localhost:8080`)?